# can rsync run gunzip on files after transferring them

Tags: rsync

I need to transfer a lot of compressed (db archive) files reliably then uncompress them on the other side. Once they are uncompressed they will be promptly ingested by the DB and then deleted.
I'm currently rsyncing the whole batch over then uncompressing all of them, then ingesting all of them. This makes poor use of my disc io and processor on the receiver and just seems inelegant.

- can i have rsync uncompress them as it copies them (either before or after)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, `rsync` can't do that on its own. There is nothing inelegant about using scripting to coordinate UNIX tools to accomplish a task.

Answer (score 0):

These options aren't bad either:

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-use-tar-command-through-network-over-ssh-session/

Answer (score 0):

No; but it can transparently use compression to speed up transmission (beyond what it gets by sending differentials).

Comment: Useful in a lot of cases. here the data starts out compressed.